# Extract IP from header using php

Tags: php, email, search

OK I'm not great with PHP but I'm learning so stay with me here.

I have an email address that all email received is piped to a php script which then stores the headers message subject etc in a database.

This works Fine but what I need to do is search the header for the senders server IP and then put that into a variable.

```
From originalguy@someplace.com Sun Dec 12 02:37:01 2010
Received: from mail-pz0-f52.google.com ([**209.85.210.52**])
        by some.server.com with esmtp (Exim 4.69) (envelope-from <razz222au@gmail.com>)
        id 1PRRVJ-00020U-1p for someguy@someplace.com;
```

Comment: go to previous question [go to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417736/extract-ip-from-header-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular expressions.

i.e.

```
if (preg_match('/\(\[((\d){1,3}\.(\d){1,3}\.(\d){1,3}\.(\d){1,3})\]\)/i', $string, $matches))
{
    print_r($matches);
}
```

- Christian

Comment: This regular expression did not work with some headers, eg: https://gist.github.com/daslicht/0c0e93fb82478a711cc1, Which is the senders ip : Received: from smtp65.yalanmail.com ([85.153.51.161]) ? Received: from localhost (5.10.69.141) by smtp.51.portakalmail.com. This one : smtp.51.portakalmail.com ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to parse the Received headers. You want to look for the *first* one, which will be the *last* one down from the top. Unless some are spoofed, which is common in spams.

Comment: When someone sends you a mail , the senders server needs to connect to yours, so how could we log those connections ? Couldn't we use this to identify the sender?

Comment: probably need to configure your SMTP server software to do verbose logging. sorry, really busy right now and can't research it.